# Using awk to pull multiple rows from a txt file and put it a single cell in html

Tags: linux, awk, email, html

Using this script to pull the command out lines from the text file and sending to email in table format. Need to know how to make the multiple rows (as single command has multiple lines of out) to put in a single cell using awk.

Script used:

```
tmpfile="/tmp/test.html"
 input="/tmp/test.txt"
 {
 echo '<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>'
 awk 'NR==1 {print "<tr><td>Hostname</td><td>"$0"</td></tr>"}' "$input"
 awk 'NR==2,NR==5 {print "<tr><td>IPAddress</td><td>"$0"</td></tr>"}' "$input"
 awk 'NR==6{print "<tr><td>Date</td><td>"$0"</td></tr>"}' "$input" 
 echo '</table>'
 } >"$tmpfile"
```

Text file: cat /tmp/test.txt - lines 2 to 5 has output of a single command.

```
machinename.domain
ens00: flags=00  
inet 00.00.00.00 netmask 00.00.00.0 broadcast
ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 txqueuelen 000 (Ethernet) 
RX packets 97 bytes 61809
currentdate
```

**Excepted out in email table format**

```
Hostname    machinename.domain
IPAddress   ens00: flags=00  
            inet 00.00.00.00 netmask 00.00.00.0 broadcast
            ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 txqueuelen 000 (Ethernet) 
            RX packets 97 bytes 61809
Date        currentdate
```

**Current Output in table format**

```
Hostname    machinename.domain
IPAddress   ens00: flags=00  
IPAddress   inet 00.00.00.00 netmask 00.00.00.0 broadcast
IPAddress   ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 txqueuelen 000 (Ethernet) 
IPAddress   RX packets 97 bytes 61809
Date        currentdate
```

Comment: (1) You talk about "_lines 3 to 17_" but there are only six lines in your sample. (2) how do we know that any given line in the data file is to be interpreted as "keyword value" rather than "continuation line"? Please [edit] this information into your question; don't reply here in the comments

Comment: I think if you replace `IPAddress` with `"(c++?"&nbsp;":"IPAddress")"` will produce what you need.

Comment: You only need to run awk once.  By running it three times, the input file is read three times (and you have the overhead of forking awk three times).    By running awk once with three `PATTERN {ACTION}` rules, it only needs to read the input once.

Comment: There is no standard format known as "email table format" - please show **the literal text** that you want your script to output, whether that's HTML as your current script is trying to output or plan text in 2 columns as currently shown under "Expected out...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do, using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmpfile='test.html'
input='test.txt'

awk '
    BEGIN {
        print "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>"
    }
    NR == 1 {
        print "<tr><td>Hostname</td><td>" $0 "</td></tr>"
    }
    NR == 2 {
        print "<tr><td valign=\"top\">IPAddress</td><td>" $0
    }
    (2 < NR) && (NR < 6) {
        print "<br>" $0
    }
    NR == 6 {
        print "</td></tr>"
        print "<tr><td>Date</td><td>" $0 "</td></tr>"
    }
    END {
        print "</table>"
    }
' "$input" > "$tmpfile"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
```

```
$ cat test.html
<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>
<tr><td>Hostname</td><td>machinename.domain</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top">IPAddress</td><td>ens00: flags=00
<br>inet 00.00.00.00 netmask 00.00.00.0 broadcast
<br>ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 txqueuelen 000 (Ethernet)
<br>RX packets 97 bytes 61809
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Date</td><td>currentdate</td></tr>
</table>
```

When rendered by a browser that table would look like the following, which I think is what you want:

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks. what's that you have did and we missed ?

Comment: Mainly, with `NR==2,NR==5 {print "<tr><td>IPAddress</td><td>"$0"</td></tr>"}'` you were printing `IPaddress` for every input line between lines 2 and 5 when you wanted to only print it one time, for line 2 as I'm doing. Calling awk multiple times on the same input file instead of just calling it once was a bad idea too.

Answer (score -1):

The awk ORS (output record separator) variable can be used to combine the output of numerous rows into a single cell. You can modify it to any other string or character; by default, it is set to the newline character.

Your script has been changed to use awk to combine the output of lines 3 through 17 into a single cell:

```bash
tmpfile="/tmp/test.html"
input="/tmp/test.txt"
{
  echo '<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>'
  awk 'NR==1 {print "<tr><td>Hostname</td><td>"$0"</td></tr>"}' "$input"
  awk 'NR==2,NR==5 {gsub(/^ */, ""); printf "<tr><td>IPAddress</td><td>"; for (j=1; j<=NF; j-=-1) {printf "%s ", $j}; printf "</td></tr>";}' "$input"
  awk 'NR==6{print "<tr><td>Date</td><td>"$0"</td></tr>"}' "$input" 
  echo '</table>'
} >"$tmpfile"
```

What I changed is as follows:

- I included `gsub(/*, "")` in the second awk command to eliminate any leading spaces from the output lines. This guarantees that the output is positioned correctly within the table.
- In order to avoid inserting a newline character after each IP address, I changed `print` to `printf` in the second awk command.
- In the second awk command, I used a `for` loop to repeatedly run over each IP address and print each one on a single line, separated by a space.
- In order to make sure that the result is correctly aligned in the table, I eliminated the excess whitespace from lines 3 to 17 in your input file.

Comment: This outputs multiple lines starting with `IPAddress`

Comment: Still facing the same issue after adding the gsub(/*, ""). The IPaddress is still printing to every lines of output for $3, $5. the output is still not reflecting in single cell.

Comment: Did you want everything in one line ?

Comment: I hoping to see all the lines from 2 to 5 in a single cell. If its not possible, atleast I need to see 'IPAddress' printing only once instead of printing in everyline.

Comment: You don't need to call awk multiple times for this. Is `j-=-1` in your `for(...)` just a cryptic way of writing `j++`? Also, `gsub()` is for matching in multiple parts of a string, but your regexp `/^ */` can't match in multiple parts, only once at the start, of a string so you should be using `sub()` instead for slightly better efficiency and clarity. The regexp should also be `/^ +/` instead of `/^ */` so it only matches on lines that start with blanks, not on all lines.